# Libgit2 : SSH : Unable to exchange encryption keys

Tags: c++, credentials, libgit2

## Background

I'm writing a Linux based application (gtkmm) that uses a single private repository hosted on github.  The application is using `Libgit2` and `SSH Authentication`.
The SSH Keys were created externally, and work fine when tested via a terminal.

I currently have two issues that more than likely correlate.

### Issue 1: Unable to Exchange Encryption Keys.

This issue occurs when attempting to clone the private repository; and is the error printed from Libgit2.
I've attempted to use `git_cred_ssh_key_new` AND `git_cred_ssh_key_from_agent` without success.

### Issue 2: The Credential Callback is never called.

I've ensured that this (`Credential` callback) has been set for clone options, fetch options, and remote callbacks; and is being used by the `git_clone()`.
A cout is inside this that is never printed; as is a GUI related text which is also not set; so I've determined this is never being called.

```cpp
int repoManager_gitCredentialCallback(git_cred **out, const char *url, const char *username_from_url, unsigned int allowed_types, void *payload){
cout << "Credentials Called" << endl;
string temp_publicKey = Global::programHomeDir + "/id_rsa.pub";
string temp_privateKey = Global::programHomeDir + "/id_rsa";
return git_cred_ssh_key_new( out, username_from_url, temp_publicKey.c_str(), temp_privateKey.c_str(), "" );
} // END - gitCredentialCallback
```

In function for cloning:

```
// SET GIT OPTIONS:
git_clone_options repoManager_cloneOptions = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
git_fetch_options repoManager_fetchOptions = GIT_FETCH_OPTIONS_INIT;
//  git_remote_callbacks repoManager_remoteCallbacks = GIT_REMOTE_CALLBACKS_INIT;
    
repoManager_cloneOptions.fetch_opts.callbacks.credentials = repoManager_gitCredentialCallback;
repoManager_cloneOptions.fetch_opts.callbacks.transfer_progress = repoManager_fetchProgress;
repoManager_cloneOptions.fetch_opts.callbacks.payload = this;
repoManager_cloneOptions.remote_cb = repoManager_gitRemoteCallback;

//  repoManager_remoteCallbacks.credentials = repoManager_gitCredentialCallback;
//  repoManager_cloneOptions.fetch_opts = repoManager_fetchOptions;

repoManager_fetchOptions.callbacks.transfer_progress = repoManager_fetchProgress;
repoManager_fetchOptions.callbacks.credentials = repoManager_gitCredentialCallback;
repoManager_fetchOptions.callbacks.payload = this;
repoManager_fetchOptions.download_tags = GIT_REMOTE_DOWNLOAD_TAGS_ALL;


if(git_clone(&repoManager_repo, repoManager_RepoURL, Global::launcherRepositoryDir.c_str(), &repoManager_cloneOptions) < 0){
    RepoManager_thread_taskFailed("Failed to Clone the repository.", "FAIL: Clone failed.");
    return;
} // END - Git Clone
```

Comment: Did you check that your remote creation callback is working properly?

Comment: Hey!  I'm not too sure what you mean?  The remote is already created on git?
Unless you meant the `remote callback`; which after faffing around I've managed to get called once, then segfaults.

Comment: @asandroq : Sorry, I see where I went wrong there! The wording and docs aren't newb friendly :P
I hadn't set up "git_remote_create" inside the callback.
However, with that fixed- the issue I posted initially still persists.  Encryption keys don't get exchanged, and the credential callback isn't called.

Comment: Do you really need a remote creation callback though?

Comment: Nope~!  Just making sure the remote isn't null/empty beforehand is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Insufficient rep for commenting, so *hopefully* this is helpful)

This error usually means there's a protocol-level problem while setting up the SSH channel, which is why you don't get to send credentials (think cipher negotiation failure).

It would be helpful to know what crypto backend is libssh2 using (I suspect it's OpenSSL), as well as its version and its backend version.
Note that libssh2 only recently gained support for something that is now the de-facto secure method (hence why it works in a terminal: your client has a supported cipher in common with the server).

Comment: Hey!  Thanks for the heads up.
It is indeed OpenSSL; had a barrel of laughs getting libgit2 to compile with SSH support.
Synaptic says libssh-4, and libssh2 are installed.
and openssl version is: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12

I've put getting SSH to work on hold for now; since https and a plaintext works.

Comment: Hi there!  There's been some updates to SSH related libraries on my machine ever since I asked this question, and out of mild curiosity today have gone back to the git test I created for SSH.  It now works! Assuming because of the updated libraries.

I've marked your answer as correct, since it hinted towards what to fix (if you're reading question looking for answers, update your libraries!).  Thanks!